# Calling a null variable vs a not initialised variable PHP

Tags: php

Is it bad to call and return a value of a not initialised variable, since its not initialised nothing will be returned. Vs returning a variable initialised to NULL.

For example:

**Not initialised variable, may return nothing if condition is false**

```
if($me === 1){
   $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
} 

echo$display_this;
```

**Initialised version**

```
$display_this = null;
if($me === 1){
   $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
} 

echo$display_this;
```

Is there any problem doing the version that you dont initialise the variable, could PHP handle it properly? without throwing back any errors?

The reason why I asked is because I find easier to read when there is less variable being initialised all over the place. I have a bit of code that has too many variables and if I initialise all of them could make that list even longer. I am fine doing this way?

Comment: Scuzzy yeah I know I could check if its isset. I would just like to know if PHP can handle the above statement fine

Comment: It can handle it but it will generate a notice in your log

Comment: Go look into the ternary operator, it allows you to write stuff like this as a nice little “one-liner” while still doing it _correctly_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP will behave the same, but raise a Notice if you do this, and there are a few reasons why it's considered "bad style". The one I find easiest to explain is if you move the code into a loop:

```
$people = [0, 1, 2, 3];
foreach ( $people as $me ) {
    if($me === 1){
       $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
    } 
    echo $display_this;
}
```

This will say "Hi!" *three times*, because the variable is not reset to blank on each iteration.

If instead you initialised it to an appropriate default (in this case, an empty string makes more sense than `null`, since you're passing it to `echo`), it would work as expected:

```
$people = [0, 1, 2, 3];
foreach ( $people as $me ) {
    $display_this = '';
    if($me === 1){
       $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
    } 
    echo $display_this;
}
```

In general, initialising a variable helps *localise* it: I know at a glance from these lines all possible values of `$display_this`, which isn't true of your version:

```
    $display_this = '';
    if($me === 1){
       $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
    } 
    echo $display_this;
```

As pointed out in comments, this example would also work if we added an `else` block:

```
$people = [0, 1, 2, 3];
foreach ( $people as $me ) {
    if($me === 1){
       $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
    } else {
       $display_this = '';
    }
    echo $display_this;
}
```

However, if the `if` and `else` blocks grow, we lose the ability to see at a glance that this variable is reset every time around the loop, and we can easily introduce a bug if we add an `elseif` block:

```
$people = [0, 1, 2, 3];
foreach ( $people as $me ) {
    if($me === 1){
       $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
    } elseif ( $me === 2 ) {
       // Do something unrelated, and forget to set $display_this
    } else {
       $display_this = '';
    }
    echo $display_this;
}
```

Finally, a note:

> I have a bit of code that has too many variables

This makes localising those variables *more* important, not less. One of the ways to refactor such code is to break it down into separate functions acting on their own set of variables, but you can't do that easily if a variable might have a value set on line 2 and used on line 200.

Comment: In the `foreach` loop, wouldn't be better to do    `if($me === 1){
       $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
    } else { $display_this = '';
     }` instead of `$display_this = '';
    if($me === 1){
       $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
    }` ? That way, `$display_this` isn't modified twice in the same iteration.

Comment: @TakitIsy Sure, in that particular example, that would be just as readable. However, as the complexity grows, it becomes harder to reason about variables that way if you don't also give them an initial value. For instance, what if you add an `elseif` block, and forget to also assign that variable there? Or what if the `if` block grows to 10 lines, and the `else` to another 10, and the assignment is not as obvious? Initialising the variable outside the condition is the only sure way to say "whatever happens, this now has a default value, and doesn't interact with previous code".

Comment: @TakitIsy Also, note that unless you're writing an embedded controller for some extremely time-critical hardware (in which case you wouldn't be using PHP), you should optimise for humans first, machines second: readability is almost always more important than microscopic performance gains like skipping a variable reset. You could argue that the `else` version makes the intent clearer, but it also makes the code longer, which might make the function as a whole harder to read.

Comment: Thank you for that nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$me = 0;
if($me === 1){
    $display_this = "<p>Hi</p>";
}

echo $display_this;
```

will give...

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: display_this ...
```

Which isn't good.  Adding

```
$display_this = null;
```

Gets rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that you aren't doing anyone any favors by not initializing your variables and it doesn't make your code more readable.

- I would argue that by not initializing you're not making your intentions clear and therefore making it more confusing to understand your code.
- If your code would really be made more confusing by adding initializations then you probably have too many variables and your code needs refactoring.
- If you find yourself doing stuff that "smells funny" or goes against common practice, you'd better really know what you're doing before embarking on your own path.

However, that's really a religious discussion.

```
<?php
$test = NULL;

var_dump($test);

var_dump($what);
```

Shows that both $test and $what return NULL.  So, practically your code should work.  Albeit with NOTICE messages:

```
php test2.php
NULL
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: what in test2.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: what in test2.php on line 6
NULL
```